# SQL query: Update single attribute (column) value to k different values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to replace an attribute value by *k* different values (which I am getting from a list, hence *k* can change depending on the size of the list). Also, the *k* different values need to be updated in equal proportion.

e.g. There is an attribute `Education` with value `University`.

Now, I want to update the table where `University` should be replaced with `Bachelors`, `Masters` or `Doctorate`.

If there are 100 tuples where `Education = University` then: 
33 should be updated to `Bachelors`, 
33 to `Masters` and 
34 to `Doctorate`.

Note: In the given example *k* = 3. I would require a query which is workable for different values of *k*. Since, I would be integrating this query in mysql with python, you may write any variable to represent *k* and list indices.

Edit: A naive approach is to first store the `count` of tuples where `Education = University`. Then dividing that count by *k* (where *k* is the length of list) and running the update query repeatedly in a for loop until the values from the list are exhausted. 
In the update query, I limit the number of rows affected by setting `limit` = count / *k*. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same?

Comment: You "require" a query that fits your constraints and we here at SO require that you put forth some effort and try something first. What have you tried thus far? Do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: Kindly check the Edit section.

Comment: It's nice that you described what you did, but it would be better to see your code so we can help guide you to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge number of different solutions in different way for different environment.
I show you an idea how to solve it with a single update. It isn’t quite optimal one but it does its work alright. Let’s say we have two tables – student(id, education) and education (name).
Then, here you are:

```
update student
    set education_new = (
        select
            --s2.id, s2.education,
            e1.name
        from (
                select (select count(*) from education x where x.rowid <= e.rowid) id, name  from education e
            ) e1,
            (
                select
                    s.id, (select count(*) from student x where x.education = 'University' and x.rowid <= s.rowid) % (select count(*) from education) + 1 as e_id
                from student s
            ) s2
        where
            e1.id = s2.e_id
            and s2.id = student.id
        )
where education = 'University'
```

In this case, you also need to run extra update:

```
update student
    set education = education_new
where
    education <> education_new
    and education_new is not null
```